# How to use template or loop to minimize the code in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to extract the forecast data from XML file to my XSLT 1.0. 
I am new to these language, so I am using same lines of code multiple times. The difference in given code is only attribute @aac on for-each loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="product/forecast/area[@aac='SA_PT001']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@description" /> :
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/text[@type='precis']"/> : Min
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/> : Max
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="product/forecast/area[@aac='QLD_PT015']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@description" /> :
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/text[@type='precis']"/> : Min
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/> : Max
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="product/forecast/area[@aac='NSW_PT027']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@description" /> :
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/text[@type='precis']"/> : Min
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/> : Max
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

can you give me idea to use loop or XSL template to reduce the code size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="aac_list">NSW_PT027,QLD_PT015,NSW_PT027</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="product/forecast/area">
    <xsl:sort select="@description"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($aac_list, ./@aac)">
        <xsl:value-of select="@description" /> :
        <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/text[@type='precis']"/> : Min
        <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/> : Max
        <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/><br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

`aac_list` variable you can build dynamically

Comment: Thank you Camobap for your help. It totally worked for me. But I also want to sort the data alphabetically by @description. Can you give me idea?

Comment: I think you can use [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xsl_sort.asp). I was updated my post

Comment: I have two if conditions inside for-each loop and both of them have <xsl:value-of select="@description" />. Now, will this code <xsl:sort select="@description"/> works on sorting? I tried to do that but it gave me random data.

Comment: Please see [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xsl_sort.asp) maybe you need set additional attribute like `lang`, `data-type`, `case-order`

Answer (score 1):

You could change the body of the for-each into a template:

```
<xsl:template match="area">
    <xsl:value-of select="@description" /> :
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/text[@type='precis']"/> : Min
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/> : Max
    <xsl:value-of select="forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='SA_PT001']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='QLD_PT015']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='NSW_PT027']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will give you all the `SA_PT001` areas first, then all the `QLD_PT015` areas, etc.  You can combine the three selects into one using

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='SA_PT001' or @aac='QLD_PT015' or @aac='NSW_PT027']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but this will give you all the areas of any of the three `aac` values in document order, rather than grouped by `aac`.

Edit: you say you want to sort alphabetically by description:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='SA_PT001' or @aac='QLD_PT015' or @aac='NSW_PT027']">
        <xsl:sort select="@description" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

will sort them all by description.  You can use more than one `<xsl:sort>` so

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="product/forecast/area[@aac='SA_PT001' or @aac='QLD_PT015' or @aac='NSW_PT027']">
        <xsl:sort select="@aac" />
        <xsl:sort select="@description" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

would first group by `aac` and then within each `aac` group sort by description.